# Using dplyr to clean data

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Take the following example:

```
set.seed(123456)
A <- 1:500
B <- sample(1:50, 500, replace = T)
C <- rep(0,500)
df1 <- data.frame(A,B,C)
df1$C[1] <- 1

library(dplyr)
```

Now I want to remove the data where the `B` values differ more than 10 relative to `df1$B[1]`

I have tried the following code using the `dplyr` package:

```
diff_in_B_less_than_10 <- df1 %>%
  filter(abs( B[C == 1] - B[C == 0]) <= 10)
```

Comment: And you want keep the data where C==1 ?

Comment: yes, please. However if easier, you can remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column with difference of df$B to df1[1,"B"]

```
df1$d <- df1$B - df1[1,"B"]
```

With dplyr, filter to retain any value between -10 and 10; and remove the dummy column created:

```
df2<-df1 %>% filter(d <= 10 & d >=-10) %>% select(-d)
```

Comment: You can include `d` in your code using `mutate`. i.e `df1 %>% mutate(d = B - B[1]) %>% filter(d <= 10 & d >=-10) %>% select(-d)`

Answer (score 2):

This uses the same ideas and gets you there:

```
diff_in_B_less_than_10 <- df1 %>% filter(abs(B - df1$B[[1]]) <= 10, C==0)
```

We just separated out the two concerns: determining the difference and filtering based on C. The two conditions are ANDed together by `filter`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `between`:

```
df1 %>% filter(between((B-B[1]), -10, 10))  # or
df1 %>% filter((B-B[1]) >= -10 & (B-B[1]) <= 10)
```